# JQuery multiple file upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I have a problem while I am trying to upload multiple files using the following code. When I tried to select multiple files, I show only first file from multiple files. How can I get all these file names with all information such as temp name and type?

Here is HTML code for multiple upload:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaxImageUpload.php' style="clear:both">
<h3>Upload your Documents Here</h3> 
<div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'><img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>
<div id='imageloadbutton'>
<style>
.col-md-4 {
    float: none;
}
</style>

<div class="col-md-4">


 <div class="input-group">
                     <label for="startDate">Select Month-Year :</label><br />
                     <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="Select Month-Year" />

                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                      <script src="js/jquery.monthpicker.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#startDate').monthpicker();

    });
    </script>


<input type="file" name="photos[]" id="photoimg" multiple="true" class="form-control" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
</div>
</form>
```

And here is the JQuery ajax call:

```
 $('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function(){ 
                   //$("#preview").html('');

         if($('#startDate').val()=='' ||  $('#startDate').val()==null )
         {
            alert("Select Month/year");
            return false;
         }
         else
         {
            var d=$('#startDate').val();
           $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mdoc_upld.php",
        data: {'startDate':d,'files': $('#photoimg').val()}
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#preview").html(data);
         });
         }
        });
```

Finally, this is how the uploaded files are processed:

```
require_once "connection.php";
define ("MAX_SIZE","9000"); 
function getExtension($str)
{
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
}


$valid_formats = array("pdf", "xls","xlsx","doc","docx");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
    print_r($_POST);exit;
    if(isset($_POST['startDate']) && $_POST['startDate'] !='')
    {
        $d=$_POST['startDate'];
       // $unixtime = 602294400;
        $time = date("Y-m",$d);
        //echo $time ;

    }
```

The call to `print_r` shows only one file name, but it should be array of all file names right?

How can I get access to all the files that were uploaded?

Comment: what does print_r($_FILES) return ??

Comment: empty array..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial for multiple image upload. [here is link to tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/09/multiple-ajax-image-upload-jquery.html)

If you want to upload pdf file or any other , you just need to replace following line in ajaxImageupload.php

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
```

with this line

```
$valid_formats = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
```

add more file extensions here.

And one more thing, if you are following this tutorial for multiple file upload for any file type, you just need to replace following code `jquery.wallform.js`

```
        var exp = /<img[^>]+>/i;

        expResult = data.match(exp);
       if(expResult == null)
       {
        alert("Something went wrong.");
       }
       else{
        $(options.target).prepend(data);
        }
```

with this code:

```
$(options.target).prepend(data);
```

Here you are done. Enjoy and credit goes to [9lessons](http://www.9lessons.info)

Comment: lets give a try as you explained and i am also following this example.now trying to change jquery.wallform.js

Comment: one more thing, use the example as it is except database insert query